# Does illuminating a conductor with light energy less than its workfunction change the measured conductivity?

Tags: visible-light, electrons, thermal-conductivity, metals

For example, does the light absorbed in an exposed metal wire increase the average velocity of the electrons, hence increasing mobility and conductance?

Comment: Interesting thought, but why would any putative photon absorption occur in free electrons (unlikely), and why would it occur so as to add to (or subtract from) the vector momentum of the carrier electrons?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, (1) why photon absorbtion is unlikely? and what do you mean by free? (delocalized?) (2) are you implying that the only observable change would be heating?

Comment: 1) because the electrons are not in orbitals and will more likely have an elastic collision 2) I'm not implying anything else.